# Flex div with flex-wrap doesn't wrap

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to get several divs to fetch the whole width and to wrap if their individual width are below 200 pixels.
This is what I did:

```css
.box {
  width: 1100px;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex-flow: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box>div {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  min-width: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

  <div>
    Boite 1
  </div>
  <div>
    Boite 2
  </div>
  <div>
    Boite 3
  </div>

</div>
```

But it doesn't wrap. What's the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three flex children with  200px `min-width` each in a container that has a width of 100%/1100px - they won't wrap as long as the overall width isn't less than 600px.

make the window narrower or add additional children, then you'll see the wrapping

```css
.box {
  width: 1100px;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex-flow: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box > div {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  min-width: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

  <div>
    Boite 1
  </div>
  <div>
    Boite 2
  </div>
  <div>
    Boite 3
  </div>
  <div>
    Boite 4
  </div>
  <div>
    Boite 5
  </div>
  <div>
    Boite 6
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Yes, in fact I didn't write the right code, it's not my problem, but thanks for this one...

Answer (score 0):

The divs will wrap if there is no more space in the container. Your container has `width: 1100px;` , so it can contain several children with width `min-width: 200px;` .

If you add more children to your container, they will wrap.